# Move an item from one Vec<T> to another while iterating

Tags: rust, iterator

I am not using a String in my case but a struct that is expensive to clone. Is there a way to remove an element and add it to another Vec in only one iteration or without Cloning? Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

```
fn move_item(vec1: &mut Vec<String>, vec2: &mut Vec<String>) {
    vec1.retain(|item| {
        if item.len() <= 5 {
            vec2.push(item.clone());
            return false;
        }
        true
    })
}
```

The other solution I thought of was iterating over the first Vec saving the indexes to remove then iterating over the indexes reversed to remove the element and then add to vec2. This is janky and remove is O(n) for every element.

Comment: Are you trying to partition your array into parts that match those conditions and parts that don't match? You could try [`partition`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition) on something you've converted `into_iter()`.

Comment: Kind of, but vec2 might already have elements in it. Would it be a good idea to partition and then append the partition to vec2?

Comment: I'd suggest splitting it out, then appending as necessary to your second vec, as well as rebuilding the first entirely. If you're just moving stuff around it should be cheap. As you point out, it's the clones that get expensive.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the unstable [`drain_filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain_filter) method, which gives you an ergonomic way to remove elements from a vector using a predicate, but also yields those items from the returned iterator so that you can move them elsewhere.  Unfortunately you will have to wait for this to be stabilized if you want to use it on stable Rust.

When it is stable, you'll be able to do this:

```
vec2.extend(vec1.drain_filter(|i| i.len() <= 5));
```

If your struct implements `Default` with a state that's cheap to represent, you could combine [`Vec::retain_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain_mut) with [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html):

```
vec1.retain_mut(|item| {
    if item.len() <= 5 {
        vec2.push(std::mem::take(item));
        return false;
    }
    true
})
```

This will swap a default `T` into `vec1`, giving you the owned `T` that you can push into `vec2`.  The default `T` is then destroyed when the predicate returns `false`.  This works well for many standard library types like `String` and `Vec`, whose `Default` implementations don't allocate, which makes them cheap to create and destroy.

Alternatively, you can always fall back on index-based iteration.

```
let mut i = 0;
while i < vec1.len() {
    if vec1[i].len() <= 5 {
        vec2.push(vec1.remove(i));
    } else {
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

This has the disadvantage of calling `remove` multiple times, which may require shifting a large number of items down repeatedly.  The `retain_mut` approach would be better as it uses an optimized algorithm to avoid this.

If order of `vec1` isn't important, you can replace `remove` with [`swap_remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap_remove), which is O(1) but doesn't preserve the relative order of retained elements.

Comment: thank you. I don't know if this is a good question but would it make since to have a vec containing all the structs and two vecs containing the indexes of those structs and pass the usize around instead of the struct itself? I am relatively new to programming so I don't know if something like this could be considered kosher.

Comment: @Diomedes That can work, you just have to be super careful that removing from the main `Vec` will suddenly make the indexes point at different elements than they used to.

Comment: I would NOT recommend the index-based iteration solution without a BIG disclaimer that its complexity is Quadratic, unlike `retain` based solutions which have Linear complexity.